# Javascript: Global variable used before local variable is used (example from jQuery JavaScript tutorial)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery tutorial on JavaScript (http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/) there is the following example on scope:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var foo = "hello";
    var myFn = function() {
        console.log( foo );
    };
    foo = "world";  // line x
    return myFn;
};
var f = myFunction();
f(); // "world"
```

Now I'm wondering why the output is *world* instead of *hello*. The variable *foo* is locally bound inside *myFunction*. Then in *myFn*, *foo* is accessed. I would say the evaluation should go down the scopes, which would be declaration inside *myFn*, then declaration inside *myFunction* and the last one should be the global variable.

So why is the global variable output even though the definition inside *myFunction* is less far away in the scope?

If I remove the line marked with *line x*, the local variable is output as expected.

Comment: `myFn` only keeps a reference of `foo` object, is not creating a copy of it.

Comment: Meaning *line x* is actually changing the local variable of myFunction, right?

Comment: Prototype chain doesn't enter into this code example. Nothing about this involves prototypes. I think you're confusing "scope" and closures with "prototype".

Comment: You are right meagar. Hope I have the naming right now after my question edit. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is a local variable in the `myFunction` context. So when you call the `myFn` function you're accessing the actual (last in this case) value of the `foo` variable.

**Note** that there's an error in the question title. `foo` **is not** global. But local to `myFunction`

Comment: The comment in the tuturial before the code is "When you reference a global variable within a function, that function can see changes to the variable value after the function is defined." It looks to me like that comment is wrong, right? There is no global variable in the code example. is there?

Comment: @mbader In your example `myFunction` and `f` are the only globals.

Comment: @mbader I think that's a problem in the tutorial's wording. `foo` is scoped to the `myFunction` closure in this example. In the tutorial, there's an example above the one you posted here and that one *does* contain a global `foo` variable.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: You are right. I didn't see that because of the description text before the example. But you are definitely right. So now it makes perfectly sense to me. Seems like it's just a problem with the wording in the tutorial. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are Objects in Javascript and Objects are passed by reference not value. Also, returning an Object is in essence passing the Object. Or, you could refer to it as returning by reference.

The myFn function being run in the global space retains the same scope it was defined in. This is what causes f() to adhere to changes made to the foo variable and to access the foo variable to begin with.

The layout of text is slightly misleading here http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/. Text referring to code further down the page is followed by a colon. The text you are referring to is for the code above it, which is most likely what was causing confusion.